# Install Certifiace on iPad into Keychain using iTunes

Tags: objective-c, ipad, certificate, itunes

I was unable to find a way how to install certificates on my iPad to a keychain using iTunes (or other tool that runs on mac os x).

I need to be able to set the group (`kSecAttrAccessGroup`, eg. `"XKFABCDEFGH.com.mycompany.myapp"`) to store the certificate under. Since there is a chain of certificates, I'll be installing all of them up to the root one. Also, the last (leaf) certificate will have private part (don't know if that makes any difference).

The alternative to this is to write a small app and compile the certificates as its resources. Then I can use SecItemAdd / SecItemUpdate to write those certificates. Downside to this is that I want to install different certificate on every device, so I'll have to compile the app several different times.

Note: The app is to be a B2B, eg. not an application for public iTunes market!

Edit: I want to use the certificates [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use), I do not require that those certificates are recognized by the iOS itself (unless it will collide with the ASIHTTPRequest library).